# how to solve $2u_x+3u_y = xu+x$ where $u(0,y) = y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Im asked to solve a PDE $2u_x+3u_y = xu+x$ where $u(0,y) = y$.

I tried to solve the problem with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics.

Hence my parametrization is $\frac{dx}{2} = \frac{dy}{3} = \frac{du}{xu(x,y)+x}$.
Then $c_1 = y-\frac{3}{2}x$ and then i need to solve an ODE $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{xu(x,y)+x}{2}$ which have a solution $c_1e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} - 1$.

Then clearly the solution is not correct when substituting $c_1$ to the 2nd solution hence $(y-\frac{3}{2}x)e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} - 1$  . How to deal with the initial value condition when solving the latest ODE?

Comment: Hint: $u(x,y)\to e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} \left(-\frac{3 x}{2}+y+1\right)-1$

Comment: The first characteristic is $$ 2y - 3x = C_{1} $$ The second characteristic is $$ u + 1 = C_{2} \exp \left( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \right) $$ Note that $C_{2} = f(C_{1})$ to get $$u + 1 = f(2y - 3x) \exp \left( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \right) \tag 1$$ Now apply the initial condition to $(1)$ $$u(0, y) + 1 = y + 1 = f(2y) \implies f(y) = \frac{y}{2} + 1$$

Comment: I dont see why 1st characteristic is what you propose since solution of the ode $3dx = 2dy$ is $y = c_1 + \frac{3}{2}x$.

Comment: But my mistake was that i didnt use $c_2 = f(c_1)$?  Instead i used $c_2=c_1$.

Comment: The characteristics $2y - 3x = C_{1}$ and $y = C_{1} + 3x/2$ are the same thing. It doesn't make sense to me why you would set the characteristics to be equal, you can't possibly know the form of $f$ until you apply the given data. Just note that the general solution is $$\phi(C_{1}, C_{2}) = \phi(2y - 3x, (u + 1) \exp(-x^{2}/4)) = 0$$ which can be rewritten in the form $(1)$ given above.